# Can Windows's Wireless Network Connection Status window be opened programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows

Can a Wireless Network Connection Status window (see attached picture) be opened programmatically? The full title of the window is "Wireless Network Connection 12 Status", and its class is "#32770 (Dialog)". It belongs to EXPLORER.EXE process.

[image]

Comment: If you really need a GUI for some reason -- It shouldn't bee too hard to program such a dialog (and realize the functionality with the command line command).

Comment: Well, if push comes to shove the program can issue a system call of `netsh wlan show interfaces` every second or two and evaluate the line with the signal strength (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-determine-wi-fi-signal-strength-windows-10#wifi_signal_strength_cmd). But I suppose there is a proper API somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, specifically you use the aptly named wlan API, [enumerate the interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanenuminterfaces), get the UID of the one you are interested in, and obtain the information from that interface with [wlanqueryinterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanqueryinterface), opcode `wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection`. That probably sounds easier than it is but it is all there.

Comment: I beg to disagree. What do you think the dialog you see in Windows does in the background!? Also, your *monitor's refresh rate* isn't even 100Hz, most likely. Why on earth do you want to poll the signal strength in such short intervals? You are not programming a drone aiming at your router "by the ear".-- 1 or 2 seconds is perfectly sufficient for a GUI which people may use e.g. to see which room has better WLAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seems if there's any other method to open an adapter properties either from command-line or programatically.

A thread of [Stack Exchange Super User](https://superuser.com/a/735294) says:

> There is no way to open up that specific property window directly.
> There's only a shortcut to the "generic" interfaces screen, being
> `ncpa.cpl`.

There's [similar form in a different site](https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/141527-configuring-network-adapter-properties-via-cmd.html) which also indicates that there's NO any specific or shortcut method (includes programmatically) to jump into a  specific network adapter properties. The OP of that site also desired to get a solution something you're finding currently.